# SQL/HIVE : How to calculate days to purchase

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

SQL/Hive: I am looking to calculate # of days to purchase by a visitor. Here is how my data looks like

```
date    visitor orders
1-Jan   A   0  
1-Jan   B   0  
4-Jan   B   1  
5-Jan   A   0  
12-Jan  A   1
```

This is the result I am expecting:

```
Days to purchase    count of visitors
0   0
1   0 
2   0
3   1
4   0
5   0
.   .
.   .
.   .
11  1
```

Any help ?

Comment: what do you mean by Days to purchase?

Comment: meaning how many days did a visitor took to purchase..for ex. in the Q above visitor A came in 1st jan but purchased on 12th. So, he took 11 days to purchase. I want to get a count for all visitors who take 0, 1, 2..etc days to purchase after they first came in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood you correctly:
what you need to do is to find the minmum date for each combination of visitor+orders

```
select visitor,orders,min(date) as min.date from table group by visitor,orders
```

this should give something like:

```
visitor orders min.date
  A         0  1-Jan 
  B         0  1-Jan
  B         1  4-Jan
  A         1  12-Jan
```

this table (lets call it tbl) can be self joined to give

```
select A.visitor,datediff(day,purchase.date,first.visit) as days.to.purchase 
from (select visitor,min.date as first.visit from tbl where orders=0) A 
inner join (select visitor,min.date as purchase.date from tbl where orders=1) B
on A.visitor=B.visitor
```

now, wrap this query with an outer query to count the visitors with same datediffs:

```
 select days.to.purchase,count(visitors) as visitors from 
 (select A.visitor,datediff(day,purchase.date,first.visit) as days.to.purchase 
    from (select visitor,min.date as first.visit from tbl where orders=0) A 
    inner join (select visitor,min.date as purchase.date from tbl where orders=1) B
    on A.visitor=B.visitor
) joined
group by days.to.purchase order by days.to.purchase
```

hope I understood you correctly. I'm not sure this is the right solution but you didn't give me much to start with :)

the full solution could be:

```
 select days.to.purchase,count(visitors) as visitors from 
 (select A.visitor,datediff(day,purchase.date,first.visit) as days.to.purchase 
    from 
(select visitor,min.date as first.visit from 
(select visitor,orders,min(date) as min.date from table group by visitor,orders) tbl where orders=0) A 
    inner join 
(select visitor,min.date as purchase.date from 
(select visitor,orders,min(date) as min.date from table group by visitor,orders) tbl where orders=1) B
    on A.visitor=B.visitor
) joined
group by days.to.purchase order by days.to.purchase
```